# Rotating classic text field with dynamic text in adobe flash

Tags: flash, adobe, flash-cs5

Am trying to have a diagonally oriented text for flash player 9 (That leaves out the new text framework TLF).
When i try to rotate the text, it is nolonger displayed(It becomes hidden) even though when i click into the text area i can confirm that the text has been rotated.

The text data is entered dynamically during serving time, so the flash is a template.

I am not so good at actionscript, but directions will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have fonts embedded in order to rotate textfields.  Make sure your font is embedded.

For more information on font embedding take a look at [this link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/embedding_fonts.html).

Comment: I posted a link showing you how to do that... it's not very difficult. If it works be sure to mark this question as answered so other people know what fixed the problem for you.

Comment: sure it does work, if i embed font. but my project does not allow font embedding? It is prohibited?

Comment: why does your project not allow embedding font? You can make the text static and that should work as well. But then you can't change it at all (Can't be dynamic).